# Using webrequest api with event page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When using webrequest api with event page, get the error :

> The 'webRequest' API cannot be used with event pages.

Looking on the net, I found this topic : http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=119613

My questions : why can't (or how can) we use both ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found [declarativeWebRequest API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest.html), that would be the solution.

Avalaible now in dev and beta channels.

Comment: In the manual Google states they would rather have extensions use content pages rather than background pages, but that isn't going to happen for any plugins that need `webRequest` access until `declarativeWebRequest` is stable.

Comment: I'd just like everyone to notice that this post was created in 2012. It's now 2015 and the `declarativeWebRequest` page reads: "Note: this API is currently on hold, without concrete plans to move to stable."

So... what are we *supposed* to do?

Comment: `declarativeWebRequest ` may be removed  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=586636

Comment: @KyawTun, Actually that means that it may not be removed too. Wtf now? Chrome really loves  making its devs be sitting ducks.

Comment: 2017...still waiting

Comment: 2019 is there any solution?

Comment: 2020 the world is collapsing, and still no solution?

Comment: @CharlesJeremyColnet The pandemic has ended and there is the brand new shining  `declarativeNetRequest` API now 

Answer (score 77):

For those who don't want to use the new [Event Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html) and would prefer to stick with [Background Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html), make sure to set `"persistent": true` in your manifest file's `background` property.

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["bootstrap.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
```

Comment: `"persistent":true` is the default value; it can be omitted.