# In chome extension mv3, how do a cross origin fetch without downloading linked documents?

Tags: javascript, http, google-chrome-extension, fetch-api, service-worker

I am writing a chrome extension that does a cross origin fetch

Here is my code. To run it load it as an unpacked  chrome extension. https://github.com/yigalirani/cross_origin_fetch

##### manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "cross origin fetch",
  "version": "1.1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "service-worker.js"
  },
  "side_panel": {
    "default_path": "sidepanel.html"
  },
  "host_permissions": ["*://*/*"],
  "permissions": [
    "sidePanel",
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "declarativeNetRequestFeedback"    
  ]
}
```

##### sidepanel.html

```html
<body>
  <button id="clicker">fetch</button>
</body>
<script src="click_to_fetch.js"></script>
```

##### click_to_fetch.js

```js
function call_fetch(){
  console.log('now calling fetch')
  fetch('https://symbolclick.com/demo/').then(res=>res.text()).then(console.log)
}
document.getElementById('clicker').onclick=call_fetch
```

##### service-worker.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  const RULE = {
    id: 1,
    condition:{urlFilter: "*://*/*",resourceTypes: ['main_frame'] },
    action: {
      type: 'modifyHeaders',
      responseHeaders: [
        {header: 'Link', operation: 'remove'},
      ],
    },
  };
  chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
    removeRuleIds: [1],
    addRules: [RULE],
  });
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', async (event) => {
  console.log('service worker: fetch',event.request.url)
  return fetch(event.request.url)
})
console.log('service worker: hello')
```

The code adds a panel to chrome sidepanel titled `cross origin fetch` with a single push button. Clicking it calls fetch and prints the result.

This would normaly be blocked by cors rules, but since the code runs as a chrome extension  with proper `host_permissions`, this works.

The problem is, that every time the fetch is called, there are some warning printed to the console of the extension:

> Refused to load the script 'https://symbolclick.com/demo/print_world.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

I did some investigation, and found out that `print_world.js` file that the error mentions is downloaded automaticly by fetch because the file is mentioned in the http headers of the fetched url:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Link: <print_world.js>; rel=preload; as=script
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

#### my question is

How do I prevent the fetch from automaticly loading the linked files?

The `service-worker.js` above tries to remove the link header using `declarativeNetRequestupdateDynamicRules`, but this doent have any effect.

Related question that works for mv2 but not for mv3 [How do I opt out of HTTP/2 server push when using fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352300/how-do-i-opt-out-of-http-2-server-push-when-using-fetch)

Comment: doesn't `removeRuleIds: [1],` remove the rule you just added, since it has an id of 1? - no idea what the order of add/remove is though

Comment: 1) Your `urlFilter` is invalid because DNR uses a different syntax. Simply remove urlFilter and the rule should start working. 2) `main_frame` is the wrong type. Use `xmlhttprequest`. 3) Note that your rule removes the header from all requests not just yours, so it's bad. Add `initiatorDomains:[chrome.runtime.id]`. P.S. removeRuleIds removes the old rules so it's correct.

Comment: Thanks you much @wOxxOm , that solved my quetion perfectly